# Selecting a specific time on a list

Tags: filtering, date-and-time

I have a files with some precessed data for different locations and the data is organized by year, month hour - the hhour is either 00 or 12 UTC and I would like to split those data by year,month and time (00 or 12). I have tried some past posts on the subject but it has not worked. I have attached a xlxs file.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1taopqUb4HYTQNOmxh_uofMSf3qcgWHyD?usp=sharing

Comment: Does `data=SemanticImport["PBLHs.xlsx"]` and `data[GroupBy[#["Day Hour(12 UTC)"]["Year"] &]]` work for you?

Comment: It seems to do the trick, but how to plot those ? In as mentioned to #flinty this file has 3 separate sheets, corresponding to different locations. So applying this "sorting" on each sheets is easier to plot later.What was really bugging is the hour reference some subsets have, namely 00 and 1 which your code and his split apart.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = Import["PBLHs.xlsx"];
sheet1 = Rest@data[[1]];(*Rest removes the header row *)
GroupBy[sheet1, DateValue[ #[[1]], {"Year", "Month", "Hour24"}] &]
(* result: an association grouping rows with the same Year, Month, and 24 hour time. *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Since the excel file has 3 different sheets, how to handle that ? Apparently , data = Import["PBLHs.xlsx",{"Data,2"]; seems not doing the job.

Comment: Change `sheet1=Rest@data[[1]]` to `Flatten[data[[All, 2 ;;]], 1]` to combine the sheets. The `[[All, 2;;]]` part skips the header row on each sheet.

Comment: It worked finely. Thx